# How do I query a document by a nested value in RethinkDB?

Tags: nested, rethinkdb

The [ReThinkDB docs](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/filter/) mention:

> Documents can be filtered in a variety of ways—ranges, **nested values**, boolean conditions, and the results of anonymous functions.

Say I have:

```
{
  name: 'Joe'
  orders: [
    {
      id: 123456,
      date: '2016-01-19T09:12:48.898000+00:00'
    }
  ]
}
```

And I would like to retrieve users who have an order with id 123456 in their orders

Per [the docs](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/filter/), I have tried using...

```
(long list of things cut out, now I've found the actual answer)
```

But I get no results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works too:

```
r.db('myapp').table('people').filter(function(person) {
  return person('orders').map(function(order){ 
    return order('id')
  }).contains(123456)
})
```

Comment: @mikemaccana - I'm just exploring how to use rethinkdb and wondering, in light of this question, do you know how (or if even possible) to go about building an index on that?

Comment: @thetaiko Best asked as it's own question!

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
r.db('myapp').table('people').filter(function(person){
  return person("orders").contains(function (order) {
    return order('id').eq(123456);
  })
})
```